# Set cart items tax class based on WooCommerce checkout field selected value

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

In WooCommerce, I need to add a "billing_legal_person" custom field to my Checkout page that is selectable between "Person" and "Company" to reflect whether the customer should be taxed as a company or as a person. Then, the applicable VAT percentage should be different according to the content of that billing_legal_person selection.

I have successfully created 2 tax classes: the default (standard) one for persons and a new "companies" class for companies.

I can also successfully apply programmatically one tax class or the other with this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'my_set_taxrate_for_billing_legal_person', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_tax_class', 'my_set_taxrate_for_billing_legal_person', 10, 2 );

function my_set_taxrate_for_billing_legal_person( $tax_class, $product ) {
    // Commenting the line below, standard tax class is applied
    $tax_class = 'companies';

    return $tax_class;
}
```

I used [Checkout Field Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-checkout-field-editor-pro/) plugin to easily create the `billing_legal_person` select field (values 'person' or 'company´).

I also managed to force the recalculation of the taxes when changing the content of my `billing_legal_person` custom field:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'my_checkout_fields_trigger_refresh', 9999 );

function my_checkout_fields_trigger_refresh( $fields ) {
   $fields['billing']['billing_legal_person']['class'][] = 'update_totals_on_change';

   return $fields;
}
```

My problem is that inside `my_set_taxrate_for_billing_legal_person()`, I'm unable to access the content of the `billing_legal_person` custom field selected by the user.

If I check `WC()->checkout->get_checkout_fields['billing_legal_person']`, I always get an empty value.

If I check `WC()->checkout->checkout->get_value('billing_first_name')`, I get the intended value (customer first name). However, if I then check `WC()->checkout->checkout->get_value('billing_legal_person')`, I get a `NULL` value. I suppose I can access `billing_first_name` because it's a standard field but I can't access `billing_legal_person` because it is a custom field, but I could not find any clue on how to access custom fields.

All approaches based on checking `$_POST['billing_legal_person']` fail because I need to show the amount of taxes to be paid BEFORE the user submits the check-out form.

Any help on how I could access the content of the `billing_legal_person` custom field from `my_set_taxrate_for_billing_legal_person()` so I can check it and return one tax class or another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use Checkout field editor plugin to add 'billing_legal_person' custom checkout field, instead we will use a hand coded function.

Also, remove your `my_set_taxrate_for_billing_legal_person()` function.

Here JavaScript, Ajax and WC_Session are required to achieve your goal.

The following code below will:

- add a custom required select field for "Legal person" in checkout and My account > edit billing address pages.
- The "Legal person" will show/hide the WooCommerce Billing Company field depending on the selected value.
- When "Company" will be selected, cart items tax rate will change to "companies" and if "Person" is selected, cart items tax rate will be reseted to default…

The Code *(commented)*:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'add_legal_person_billing_field');
function add_legal_person_billing_field( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing_company']['class'][] = 'hidden'; 

    $fields['billing_legal_person'] = array(
        'label'       => __( 'Legal person', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'        => 'select',
        'options'     => [
            ''        => __("Choose an option",  "woocommerce"),
            'Person'  => __("Person",  "woocommerce"),
            'Company' => __("Company", "woocommerce"),
        ],
        'required'    => true,
        'priority'    => 25,
    );
    return $fields;
}

// Validate Billing company field
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'validate_custom_checkout_fields' );
function validate_custom_checkout_fields() {
    if ( isset($_POST['billing_legal_person']) && $_POST['billing_legal_person'] === 'Company' 
    && isset($_POST['billing_company']) && empty($_POST['billing_company']) ) {
        wc_add_notice('Billing company is a required field.', 'error');
    }
}

// PHP: Replace "(optional)" with required for Billing company
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'remove_checkout_optional_fields_label', 10, 4 );
function remove_checkout_optional_fields_label( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Only on checkout page
    if( ( ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) 
    || is_wc_endpoint_url('edit-address') ) && $key === 'billing_company' ) {
        $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        $required = '&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>';
        $field = str_replace( $optional, $required, $field );
    }
    return $field;
}

// Hide Billing company field on checkout page load 
add_action('wp_head', 'checkout_legal_person_css');
function checkout_legal_person_css() {
    if ( ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) || is_wc_endpoint_url('edit-address') ) : ?>
    <style>
        #billing_company_field.hidden {display:none !important;}
    </style>
    <?php endif;
}

// JavaScript / Ajax: Show/hide billing company and set the tax rate via Ajax
add_action( 'template_redirect' , 'checkout_legal_person_js' );
function checkout_legal_person_js() {
    if ( ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) || is_wc_endpoint_url('edit-address') ) :

    $legal_person = WC()->customer->get_meta('billing_legal_person');
    if ( is_checkout() && $legal_person ) {
        WC()->session->set('legal_person', $legal_person);
    }
    
    wc_enqueue_js("
        const company         = '#billing_company',       
              companyField    = company+'_field', 
              legalPers       = '#billing_legal_person',
              isCheckout      = ".( is_checkout() ? 'true' : 'false' ).";

        function showHideCompanyField( legalPers, companyField ) {
            if ( $(legalPers).val() === 'Company' ) {
                $(companyField).show();
            } else {
                $(companyField).hide();
            }
        }

        // On start:
        $(legalPers).selectWoo();
        $(companyField).addClass('validate-required woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field');
        showHideCompanyField( legalPers, companyField );
        $(companyField).removeClass('hidden');

        // On Legal Person change: Show/Hide company field
        $('form.woocommerce-checkout,.woocommerce-edit-address form').on('change', legalPers, function() {
            showHideCompanyField( legalPers, companyField );
            
            if ( isCheckout ) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '".admin_url('admin-ajax.php')."',
                    data: {
                        'action': 'legal_person_tax',
                        'legal_person' : $(legalPers).val(), 
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    ");
    endif;
}

// PHP AJAX receiver: Set "legal_person" session variable
add_action('wp_ajax_legal_person_tax', 'set_legal_person_tax' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_legal_person_tax', 'set_legal_person_tax' );
function set_legal_person_tax() {
    if ( isset($_POST['legal_person']) && ! empty($_POST['legal_person']) ) {
        WC()->session->set('legal_person', esc_attr($_POST['legal_person']));
    }
    wp_die(esc_attr($_POST['legal_person']));
}

// Dynamically change tax rate based on chosen "legal_person"
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'define_cart_item_tax_class_for_companies');
function define_cart_item_tax_class_for_companies( $cart )
{
    if ((is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')))
        return;

    if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') >= 2)
        return;

    $legal_person = WC()->session->get('legal_person');
    $legal_person = $legal_person ? $legal_person : WC()->customer->get_meta('billing_legal_person');

    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $item) {
        if ( $legal_person === 'Company' ) {
            $item['data']->set_tax_class('companies'); // Set tax class
        } else {
            $item['data']->set_tax_class('');
        }
    }
}

// Remove session variable when order is placed
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'unset_legal_person_session_variable');
function unset_legal_person_session_variable() {
    WC()->session->__unset('legal_person');
}

// Change tax rate if customer is a a company
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'tax_rate_based_on_chosen_legal_person', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_tax_class', 'tax_rate_based_on_chosen_legal_person', 10, 2 );
function tax_rate_based_on_chosen_legal_person( $tax_class, $product ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return $tax_class;
    
    $legal_person = WC()->customer->get_meta('billing_legal_person');

    if ( $legal_person === 'Company' ) {
        $tax_class = 'companies';
    }
    return $tax_class;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: It wasn't working for me because until today I had no access to functions.php nor to the plugins directory, so I had to test it with WPCode. After I gained access, it worked like a charm! Just to understand it: the reason for not working inside WPCode is that Ajax queries don't get routed to code inside WPCode and similar plugins?