Change the tax class according to the field selected when completing the order
Based on the code from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77626133/21533506 I have the following code:
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'add_legal_person_billing_field');
function add_legal_person_billing_field($fields)
{
    $fields['billing_company']['class'][] = 'hidden';

    $fields['billing_legal_person'] = array(
        'label'       => __('Legal person', 'woocommerce'),
        'type'        => 'select',
        'options'     => [
            ''        => __("Choose an option",  "woocommerce"),
            'Person'  => __("Person",  "woocommerce"),
            'Company' => __("Company", "woocommerce"),
        ],
        'required'    => true,
        'priority'    => 25,
    );

    $fields['billing_cui'] = array(
        'label'       => __('CUI', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'       => array('form-row-wide', 'hidden'),
        'priority'    => 26,
    );

    $fields['billing_nr_reg_com'] = array(
        'label'       => __('Nr. Reg. Com.', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'       => array('form-row-wide', 'hidden'),
        'priority'    => 27,
    );

    return $fields;
}

// Validate Billing company field
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'validate_custom_checkout_fields');
function validate_custom_checkout_fields()
{
    if (isset($_POST['billing_legal_person']) && $_POST['billing_legal_person'] === 'Company') {
        if (empty($_POST['billing_company'])) {
            wc_add_notice('Billing company is a required field.', 'error');
        }
        if (empty($_POST['billing_cui'])) {
            wc_add_notice('CUI is a required field.', 'error');
        }
        if (empty($_POST['billing_nr_reg_com'])) {
            wc_add_notice('Nr. Reg. Com. is a required field.', 'error');
        }
    }
}

// PHP: Replace "(optional)" with required for Billing fields
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field', 'remove_checkout_optional_fields_label', 10, 4);
function remove_checkout_optional_fields_label($field, $key, $args, $value)
{
    // Only on checkout page or edit address page
    if (((is_checkout() && !is_wc_endpoint_url()) || is_wc_endpoint_url('edit-address'))) {
        // Array of fields to check
        $fields_to_check = ['billing_company', 'billing_cui', 'billing_nr_reg_com'];

        if (in_array($key, $fields_to_check)) {
            $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__('optional', 'woocommerce') . ')</span>';
            $required = '&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>';
            $field = str_replace($optional, $required, $field);
        }
    }
    return $field;
}

// Hide Billing company field on checkout page load 
add_action('wp_head', 'checkout_legal_person_css');
function checkout_legal_person_css()
{
    if ((is_checkout() && !is_wc_endpoint_url()) || is_wc_endpoint_url('edit-address')) : ?>
        <style>
            #billing_company_field.hidden,
            #billing_cui_field.hidden,
            #billing_nr_reg_com_field.hidden {
                display: none !important;
            }
        </style>
<?php endif;
}

// JavaScript / Ajax: Show/hide billing company and set the tax rate via Ajax
add_action('template_redirect', 'checkout_legal_person_js');
function checkout_legal_person_js()
{
    if ((is_checkout() && !is_wc_endpoint_url()) || is_wc_endpoint_url('edit-address')) :

        $legal_person = WC()->customer->get_meta('billing_legal_person');
        if (is_checkout() && $legal_person) {
            WC()->session->set('legal_person', $legal_person);
        }

        wc_enqueue_js("
        const company         = '#billing_company',       
              companyField    = company+'_field',
              cui             = '#billing_cui',
              cuiField        = cui+'_field',
              nrRegCom        = '#billing_nr_reg_com',
              nrRegComField   = nrRegCom+'_field',
              legalPers       = '#billing_legal_person',
              isCheckout      = " . (is_checkout() ? 'true' : 'false') . ";

        function showHideCompanyFields(legalPers, companyField, cuiField, nrRegComField) {
            if ($(legalPers).val() === 'Company') {
                $(companyField).show().addClass('validate-required');
                $(cuiField).show().addClass('validate-required');
                $(nrRegComField).show().addClass('validate-required');
            } else {
                $(companyField).hide().removeClass('validate-required');
                $(cuiField).hide().removeClass('validate-required');
                $(nrRegComField).hide().removeClass('validate-required');
            }
        }

        // On start:
        $(legalPers).selectWoo();
        showHideCompanyFields(legalPers, companyField, cuiField, nrRegComField);
        $(companyField).removeClass('hidden');
        $(cuiField).removeClass('hidden');
        $(nrRegComField).removeClass('hidden');

        // On Legal Person change: Show/Hide company fields
        $('form.woocommerce-checkout,.woocommerce-edit-address form').on('change', legalPers, function() {
            showHideCompanyFields(legalPers, companyField, cuiField, nrRegComField);
            
            if (isCheckout) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '" . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . "',
                    data: {
                        'action': 'legal_person_tax',
                        'legal_person': $(legalPers).val(), 
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    ");
    endif;
}

// PHP AJAX receiver: Set "legal_person" session variable
add_action('wp_ajax_legal_person_tax', 'set_legal_person_tax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_legal_person_tax', 'set_legal_person_tax');
function set_legal_person_tax()
{
    if (isset($_POST['legal_person']) && !empty($_POST['legal_person'])) {
        WC()->session->set('legal_person', esc_attr($_POST['legal_person']));
    }
    wp_die(esc_attr($_POST['legal_person']));
}

// Dynamically change tax rate based on chosen "legal_person"
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'define_cart_item_tax_class_for_companies');
function define_cart_item_tax_class_for_companies($cart)
{
    if ((is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')))
        return;

    if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') >= 2)
        return;

    $legal_person = WC()->session->get('legal_person');
    $legal_person = $legal_person ? $legal_person : WC()->customer->get_meta('billing_legal_person');

    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $item) {
        if ($legal_person === 'Company') {
            $item['data']->set_tax_class('tva-firma'); // Set tax class
        } else {
            // Leave the product's tax class as is (so it respects any specific tax class set for the product)
            $item['data']->set_tax_class($item['data']->get_tax_class());
        }
    }
}

// Remove session variable when order is placed
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'unset_legal_person_session_variable');
function unset_legal_person_session_variable()
{
    WC()->session->__unset('legal_person');
}

// Change tax rate if customer is a company
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'tax_rate_based_on_chosen_legal_person', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_tax_class', 'tax_rate_based_on_chosen_legal_person', 10, 2);
function tax_rate_based_on_chosen_legal_person($tax_class, $product)
{
    if (is_admin()) return $tax_class;

    $legal_person = WC()->session->get('legal_person');
    $legal_person = $legal_person ? $legal_person : WC()->customer->get_meta('billing_legal_person');

    if ($legal_person === 'Company') {
        $tax_class = 'tva-firma';
    }
    return $tax_class;
}


How can I make the tax rate reset every time the page is reloaded? I want that if I selected a certain type of person (person or company) when I reload the page or go to another page, nothing is selected. I still tried to make it reset the fields when the page is reloaded, but I didn't manage to make it functional.
Please help me make it functional!
Thank you in advance!
